# System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.calendar cause throw an exception

Tags: asp.net, .net

I use this code to change my Culture to persianculture in .Net3.5:

```
if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString() == "fa-IR")
        {
            CultureInfo persianCalture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
            DateTimeFormatInfo info = persianCalture.DateTimeFormat;
            info.AbbreviatedDayNames = new string[] { "&nbsp;&nbsp;ی&nbsp;&nbsp;", "&nbsp;&nbsp;د&nbsp;&nbsp;", "&nbsp;&nbsp;س&nbsp;&nbsp;", "&nbsp;&nbsp;چ&nbsp;&nbsp;", "&nbsp;&nbsp;پ&nbsp;&nbsp;", "&nbsp;&nbsp;ج&nbsp;&nbsp;", "&nbsp;&nbsp;ش&nbsp;&nbsp;" };
            info.DayNames = new string[] { "يکشنبه", "دوشنبه", "سه‌شنبه", "چهارشنبه", "پنجشنبه", "جمعه", "شنبه" };
            info.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new string[] { "فروردين", "ارديبهشت", "خرداد", "تير", "مرداد", "شهريور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", "" };
            info.MonthNames = new string[] { "فروردين", "ارديبهشت", "خرداد", "تير", "مرداد", "شهريور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", "" };
            info.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = new string[] { "فروردين", "ارديبهشت", "خرداد", "تير", "مرداد", "شهريور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", "" };
            info.AMDesignator = "صبح";
            info.PMDesignator = "عصر";
            info.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy/MM/dd";
            info.FullDateTimePattern = "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss";
            info.LongDatePattern = "yyyy MMMM dd dddd";
            info.FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday;
            persianCalture.DateTimeFormat = info;
            PersianCalendar PersianCal = new PersianCalendar();

            typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo).GetField("calendar", (System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | (System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance))).SetValue(info, PersianCal);
            typeof(CultureInfo).GetField("calendar", (System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | (System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance))).SetValue(persianCalture, PersianCal);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = persianCalture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = persianCalture;
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat = info;
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat = info;
        }
```

but below line is throws an ArgumentNullException :

System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.calendar

```
        typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo).GetField("calendar", (System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | (System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance))).SetValue(info, PersianCal);
        typeof(CultureInfo).GetField("calendar", (System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | (System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance))).SetValue(persianCalture, PersianCal);
```

Does anybody know why this exception throw?

thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo).GetProperty("Calendar"....)`

DateTimeFormatInfo has a Calendar property (Capital C).

Hope this helps,

Shai.